# Android: float - get rid of trailing point zeros

Tags: android

i did a lot of search on the internet but could not get a satisfacting solution.
The best I did was:

```
String b = new BigDecimal(floatNumber.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

But it hast some nasty bugs, e.g. if the number is 1.6 i get 1.600000744 (or similar).

thanks

Comment: Are you really saying that 1.6 becomes 16, or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is really not a bug, it's just a result of using floating point numbers with limited precision. It can't accurately represent 1.6.

If you want the print to cut off digits past a certain point, you can do so with the DecimalFormat as previously mentioned:

`String result = new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(floatNumber).toString()`

This will print two decimal places, add as many #'s as you want after the decimal to be cut off. But what you're seeing is technically the correct value of floatNumber, even if you don't want that much precision.

Comment: if i print out float 1.6 it looked correct. I have numbers with not more than 2 digits after the . like 2.55, some with one like 1.6 and most are without decimal places. how do i get them to look nice? i dont want to have 1.00's

Comment: Read the DecimalFormat documentation, it will have your answer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
DecimalFormat twoDecForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

String b = twoDecForm.format(Double.parseDouble(Float.toString(floatNumber)));
```